# How To Change Color of Text On Different View Controller

Tags: swift, rgb, cgfloat

I have 3 RGB sliders in my settings tab that change the color of the background of that specific ViewController. I would also like it to change the color of a text label. The thing is, the text label is on a different view controller. Which means I may probably have to use **NSUserDefaults**. The text label is a quote on the QOTD Tab.

**Problem:**
How do I change the color of a text label on a different ViewController and let that color be saved until changed?

```
import UIKit

class colorSliders: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var redSlider: UISlider!
@IBOutlet weak var greenSlider: UISlider!
@IBOutlet weak var blueSlider: UISlider!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    updateBackgroundColor()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

@IBAction func updateBackgroundColor() {
    let red = CGFloat(redSlider.value)
    let green = CGFloat(greenSlider.value)
    let blue = CGFloat(blueSlider.value)

    view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: 1)
}




}
```

This is the code for the RGB sliders.

The ViewController with the quote on it contains:

UILabel! = quoteDisplay

If you need more information, feel free to comment what you would like to see and I will add it immediately. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Where is the `viewController` with the `textLabel` in relation to your color slider? does the slider push the `viewController`? or does the `viewController` push the sliders `viewController`?

Comment: It is in the same Tab Bar controller as the colorSliders.swift

Answer (score 0):

`NSUserDefaults` is probably not a good idea for a small set of specific values. I suggest declaring a structure with static variables, one that can be shared throughout your code:

```
struct UserInterfaceSettings
{
    static var myColor: UIColor! = UIColor.whiteColor()
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how does this play into changing my UILabel? isn't there any other code that I must establish in order for it to work?